# How to prevent a document prefetch deciding to additionally prefetch a non-existent stylesheet?

Tags: html, node.js, express, browser, prefetch

In my app, I'm returning a special element which dynamically prefetches a page using an Interaction Observer. Here's what the code returned looks like:

```
<a href="/api/hello" class=" stl_L834CyvXSJLS1ey">
    Go to about page
    <script data-stl="">const stl_L834CyvXSJLS1ey = 
        document.querySelector('.stl_L834CyvXSJLS1ey'); 
        new IntersectionObserver(()=>{ document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="prefetch" 
        href="/api/hello" as="document" />'}, {root: stl_L834CyvXSJLS1ey,rootMargin: 
        "500px",threshold: 0}).observe(stl_L834CyvXSJLS1ey)
    </script>
</a>
```

It has worked well in most cases, however, it recently started behaving really weird.
My page imports a stylesheet, which after being fetched is automatically deleted off the server; that basically means that it can't be fetched twice. Here's the link code:

[image]

***However, when prefetching hello, the same Intraction Observer also calls for a second fetch of the stylesheet.***
Here's a screenshot of the network tab:

[image]

As you can see, the Interaction Observer causes the second fetch of the stylesheet:
[image]

And it for some reason requires a random chance to reproduce >
**I have tried investigating where this issue happens and it is truly unexplainable:**

- Chrome: Everything is fine
- Chrome in Incognito mode: Happens
- Opera GX (Both modes): Everything is fine
- Opera One (Both modes): Happens
- Microsoft Edge (Both modes): Happens

I never noticed this behavior until now where the functionality of a JS Framework I'm building is ruined by lack of logic in a browser's design. Is this a known of bug, or is this something that has to be avoided in some way?

Please comment any paths I could take to to avoid this double fetching issue